# Выпадающий список и горизонтальный

Tags: html, css, jquery

Всем привет. Нужно сделать список. Но есть одно но. Как сделать так, чтобы на телефоне он был выпадающим, а на пк просто горизонтальный? Два делать не вариант.

Спасибо заранее за ответы :)

Comment: Ну, на разных устройствах можно сделать разные css с помощью `@media`. Почитайте об этом: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: Тоесть он должен выглядить как select, а на пк горизонтально все внутренние элементы лежать. Про media запросы знаю. Не знаю как именно это все првоернуть

Comment: Тут вот есть [парочка идей](https://codepen.io/webrajendra/pen/VvjgYY), надо только прикрутить всё к медиа-запросам и нужной ширине.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы менять стили списка, исходя из ширины экрана, вы можете проверить ширину экрана и использовать медиа запросы:

[CSS3-медиазапросы](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/)

```css
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ... тут стили для телефона и планшета
}
</style>
```

Comment: Это понятно, но мне нужен выпадающий по типу select

Comment: Вы можете регулировать вид списка через css стили. Смысл в том, что структура будет одна, а отображение такое какое вы захотите и настроите через css

Comment: Вот как раз у меня проблема со структурой. Мне это все реализовать через список? Тогда я понимаю как будет работать горизонтальный. Но не понимаю как выпадающий. На что кликать, чтобы он раскрылся, если он сам и есть то, что должно выпадать???

Comment: На самом деле вариантов достаточно много. Вы можете взглянуть на примеры того как это реализовали на бутстрап4 например https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/ Попробуйте поизменять размер экрана чтобы видеть как изменяется навигация. Либо найти что-то другое, примеров полно